# Scope by greater number considering multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In a Rails (6) app, I have the `Course` model with the following attributes

- subject (string)
- room (string)
- edition (integer)

Now, I'm trying to create a `scope` with returns, for each `subject` + `room` duo, the record with the greatest `edition`.

So, having the following record in the DB

```
|subject|room |edition|
| math  | A001| 1     |
| math  | A001| 2     |
| math  | A002| 1     |
| chem  | A002| 1     |
| chem  | A002| 2     |
| chem  | A002| 3     |
```

`Course.current` returns

```
[<Course subject: 'math', room: 'A001', edition: 2>,
 <Course subject: 'math', room: 'A002', edition: 1>,
 <Course subject: 'chem', room: 'A002', edition: 3>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
def self.current
  Course.select('max(edition) as edition, subject, room').group('subject, room')
end
```